# Front-end registration form with password field

Tags: front-end, user-registration, password

I'm trying to create a front-end registration form for my Wordpress website. The registration form is in the header, so any plugins I've seen don't work as they use shortcodes.

Look at my website for a better explanation. I want the registration form to work in the dropdown box at the top of the page.

Comment: _How_ did you try that? Couldn’t you just use the callback functions for the shortcode handlers?

Comment: I didn't know this was possible outside of the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use a plugin that uses shortcode you can call it in your template by using this in your template:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode ('[your-shortcode]'); ?>
```

You can also do something similar to this form / code below for a front end login:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php" class="wp-user-form">
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Username'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="log" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_login)); ?>" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="11" />
            </div>
            <div class="password">
                <label for="user_pass"><?php _e('Password'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" value="" size="20" id="user_pass" tabindex="12" />
            </div>
            <div class="login_fields">
                <div class="rememberme">
                    <label for="rememberme">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="forever" checked="checked" id="rememberme" tabindex="13" /> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <?php do_action('login_form'); ?>
                <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Login'); ?>" tabindex="14" class="user-submit" />
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: I'm using the do_shortcode tag now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to of helped. :) if this worked for you please do not forget to up vote and accept as your answer. @Swen

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed similar stuff and went with a sliding panel. Released it on plugins repo - schemeable-sliding-panel. See whether it suits your requirement.